# Error when starting nginx service on debian

Tags: php, nginx, debian

Server OS:Debian 8 "Jesse"

I have tried to run the nginx service using "sudo service nginx start" which will result in failure. I then use the command "sudo nginx -t" to see what the issue is and this is the error that appears

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "root" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:39

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

For more background here are lines 36 - 39 of my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file

```
root /var/www/my_web_directory
# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm;
```

More back story for anyone who may need to know.
Im trying to run mybb this is why I added "index.php" to the file

This issue has really been bothering me and I dont know any way to get around this. So if any has any answers please post your response. If you need anymore details feel free to ask and I will provide.

-John

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon after "root /var/www/my_web_directory"?

Comment: I will try that and see what happens.